# How to use NS_OPTIONS defined in Obj-C class in Swift

Tags: swift

I have to use an Objective-C static library in my Swift project. Anything else goes well but the `NS_OPTIONS` enum defined in the Objective-C header file, like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, MyOption) {
    MyOptionNone   = 0,
    MyOptionTop    = 1 << 0,
    MyOptionLeft   = 1 << 1,
    MyOptionBottom = 1 << 2,
    MyOptionRight  = 1 << 3
};

@interface MyObjcClass : NSObject

@end
```

and then in the .swift file, how could I use this enum in a switch-case?

EDIT:
I use `MyOption` in my Swift class:

```
let option1: MyOption = .Top
let option2: MyOption = .Bottom
let value = option1 & option2
```

then I get compile error:

```
Binary operator '&' cannot be applied to two `MyOption` operands
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you need to fix your syntax. You need a semicolon after the closing brace:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, MyOption) {
    MyOptionNone   = 0,
    MyOptionTop    = 1 << 0,
    MyOptionLeft   = 1 << 1,
    MyOptionBottom = 1 << 2,
    MyOptionRight  = 1 << 3
};
```

Next, in your bridging header, you need to import the header file that defines `MyOption`. When you first create a Swift source file to an Objective-C project, or when you first create an Objective-C source file in a Swift project, Xcode offers to create the bridging header for you. It's named `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`. So for example:

[image: bridging header]

Once you've done this, and both header files can be compiled without errors, you can use `MyOption` from Swift. It's an `OptionSetType`. Example:

[image: MyOption usage]

Comment: Hi, rob, I know this, but what if I want to use MyOption in switch-case?  "case .Top " will cause compile error:Enum case "Top" not found in type MyOption

Comment: Using it in a switch-case doesn't make sense, because the `MyOption` value might contain multiple options, e.g. it might contain both `.Top` and `.Bottom`, so it would need to match multiple cases and a Swift switch statement can't  do that. You should use `if options.contains(.Top) { ... } if options.contains(.Bottom) { ... }`.

Comment: Hi~ I encounter another problem. Could you help me?